# SQL: How to get the different value from one column/type?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sum the total number from a *name* table below:

```
id  type  num
2   0     90
24  1     38
2   1     878
9   0     8763
9   2     76
9   1     374
```

There are three types in the `type` column, I would like to find all ids which their `type = 0` and `1`. for example, in the table, the `id = 2` and `id = 9` have the `type = 0` and `type = 1`. So will pick these data and add them together like below:

```
       type: num
id 2 - 0:90
       1:878

id 9 - 0:8763
       1: 374

sum = 90 + 878 + 8764 + 374 = 10,106
```

I did the query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(num) FROM  table WHERE type = 0 AND type = 1;
```

ut there is nothing to show. It workq if I change the query to the `type = 0 OR type = 1`, but I do not think its right. How to sum `num` where `type = 0` and `type = 1`?

I am very confused, I am not sure am I explain clearly, if you can give some helps it will be very appreciated.

Comment: `where type = 0 and type = 1`.  Do you think this will give you any result?  The two condition together will never be true.  A record can't be both type 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
  select id from tablename
  where type in (0, 1)
  group by id
  having min(type) = 0 and max(type) = 1
```

you get all the ids that have both types 0 and 1. 
So you join it to the table to get the total you want:

```
select sum(t.num) total 
from tablename t inner join (
  select id from tablename
  where type in (0, 1)
  group by id
  having min(type) = 0 and max(type) = 1
) g on g.id = t.id
where t.type in (0, 1)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nMZ7iQPaYd3ZNaAVDxaPaa/0)
Or without join:

```
select sum(t.num) total from (
  select id, sum(num) num from tablename
  where type in (0, 1)
  group by id
  having min(type) = 0 and max(type) = 1
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nMZ7iQPaYd3ZNaAVDxaPaa/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
select
  sum(a.num + b.num)
from (
  select id, num from table where type = 0
) a
join (
  select id, num from table where type = 1
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question well the answer is quite easy:

```
SELECT SUM(num)
FROM name
WHERE type = 0 OR type = 1
```

You want to sum all `num` values from the rows where type = 0 or `type = 1`. That's exactly what the above *SQL* query expresses. Which you've actually come to as well.

Is it that what you need @lily?